# Canon EOS software

Tags: software-installation, canon

I'm a complete novice with Ubuntu. I managed to install it on my computer but now I need to put my image editing software for my Canon EOS camera onto the computer. On running the .exe file I am informed that `An error occurred while loading the archive.` The software loaded fine onto my XP  -running laptop.

I'm also getting the report listed below:

```
zipinfo:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /media/CanonEOS241W/setup.exe or
      /media/CanonEOS241W/setup.exe.zip, and cannot find /media/CanonEOS241W/setup.exe.ZIP, period.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't run windows executables directly inside ubuntu... instead, the system tries to open the file with a zip extractor, and that's why you get the error.

You should try to use an alternative image editing software native to Linux, like `gimp`, which you can find in you software center.

Or, if you insist in using this specific software, you could try opening it with `wine`... first, you should install it from ubuntu software center too. After it is installed, you'll have the option to open your executable with wine. Here you can check if your specific software has already been tested by wine users: http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?bIsQueue=false&bIsRejected=false&sClass=vendor&iId=1150&sAction=view&sTitle=View+Developer